Is there a VerticalGrid counterpart to XtraGrid RefreshRow event?
I want to implement in the VerticalGrid something I've done in the XtraGrid. The XtraGrid offers a RefreshRow(rowHandle) method, which confines the refresh to a single row in the grid. Is there something comparable which confines the refresh to a single record in the VerticalGrid when it is in multi-record view?
